# Stopping rule for decision tree

Tags: cart

There are various stopping rules when building a decision tree. For example: if node is all of the same class, then do not split further. (This rule is clear).

Some of these rules are listed [here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=jYrJDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA316&lpg=PA316&dq=If%20all%20cases%20in%20a%20node%20have%20identical%20values%20for%20each%20predictor,%20the%20node%20will%20not%20be%20split&source=bl&ots=rYor7QyZ1M&sig=ACfU3U2TGHyA6z0ijQkf8tHRAqJ-iJuAgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0saTR473oAhXQSH0KHR5tC7YQ6AEwA3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=If%20all%20cases%20in%20a%20node%20have%20identical%20values%20for%20each%20predictor%2C%20the%20node%20will%20not%20be%20split&f=false), of which I do not understand:

> 2. If all cases in a node have identical values for each predictor, the node will not be split.

An example for, say, continuous predictor variables in the context of classification would be much appreciated.

Comment: In case (2), all points assigned to the node are identical, so there is no rule that can split them and splitting should stop.

Comment: @user20160 I think you can convert your comment to an answer

Comment: So in the node all points are of the form, say, (x,1) or (x,0) (in the binary classification case)?